# How to make words in an align/equation environment not look weird

Tags: math-mode

If I have an align/equation environment (Or any environment which is maths based) like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
y_{vertical} = k \sin{x}
\end{equation}



\end{document}
```

How can I make the word "vertical" in the maths enviroment not look really odd and italic?

Comment: `\text{vertical}`

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE.

Comment: or: `y_{\mathrm{vertical}}`.

Comment: `\mathrm` is better than `\text` here

Comment: @CarLaTeX - Done. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're loading the `amsmath` package anyway, writing

```
y_{\mathrm{vertical}}
```

will do what you're looking to achieve. Better still, write

```
y^{}_{\mathrm{vertical}}
```

to get a slightly more pronounced downward shift of the subscript material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
y^{}_{\mathrm{vertical}} = k \sin{x}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```